# Facebook API for Message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is is possible using the facebook API to retrieve all the messages between someone and his friend?

What is I found is this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/message,

for getting individual messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the edge `/me/inbox` [1], this will return a list of Thread objects, the thread objects will then contain the messages. Be aware that this requires the `read_mailbox` permission which is reserved for Apps [2] that are built for platforms where no native Facebook clients exists.

Example: if you are building an iOS app, Facebook will not approve you for this permission as there already is an app for iOS.

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/inbox
[2] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-read_mailbox